# Broken tab completion on make under linux

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, tab-completion

I have no idea how tab completion works, but all of a sudden mine is broken. I don't even know what info to provide other than the use case.
there is a target `clean` in the makefile.

`$ make c<tab>` results in

`$ make c23:set: command not found
lean`

**EDIT:**
I believe somehow I ruined the `set` bash built-in since `man set` says `No manual entry for set` and `which set` doesn't report anything. Invoking set on the terminal, however, produces result.

I'm using: *GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)* and *GNU Make 3.81*

Comment: There is no `man` page for `set`. Try `help set` (`help` is an internal BASH command) or `man bash` or `info bash`.

Comment: What do `type set` and `command set` return in the shell? What do you get if you run `set -x` and then trigger this issue?

Comment: `type set` says it's a bash built in. `command set` spits out all my environment variables and a ton of bash functions. `set -x` produces this regarding the error: + 23:set +o posix bash: 23:set: command not found

Comment: @user1794469 my problem was related to an alias. try to remove yours and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @EtanReisner your comment helped the most. would you post it as an answer to mark it solved ?

Comment: I meant `command -V set`, sorry. Though given the solution here that wouldn't have helped any either.

Comment: You solved it I just helped debug it. Accept your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thanks to [Etan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932672/broken-tab-completion-on-make-under-linux?noredirect=1#comment50554123_26932672) and Aaron's indication of where makefiles are, I managed to debug this.

I ran `set -x` so I could track what was happening when doing the tab completion. The output of `make c<tab>` consists mostly of commands from the bash completion file for `make`, located at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make` (1).
However, I noticed the an inconsistency between the output and the file. Towards the end, the output said:

```
+ local mode=--
+ ((  COMP_TYPE != 9  ))
++ set +o
++ grep --colour=auto -n -F posix
+ local 'reset=23:set +o posix'
+ set +o posix
```

Which I identified as corresponding to these lines from the file:

```
if (( COMP_TYPE != 9 )); then
    mode=-d # display-only mode
fi

local reset=$( set +o | grep -F posix ); set +o posix # for <(...)
```

So the output did a `grep --colour=auto -n` instead of just `grep`. Indeed, I had setup this alias for `grep`

Make worked as soon as I removed the alias.

I hope this helps others debug their problems.

EDIT: I have submitted a bug report here: https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315108&group_id=100114&atid=413095

Comment: isn't this almost a bug ? I mean this script should use /usr/bin/grep instead of relying on potential user aliases? Anyway thanks for the solution, I also had the same alias in my bashrc file.

Comment: Indeed, being broken by user aliases is a somewhat serious flaw in this completion script. It should be using a variety of things to prevent that from happening.

Comment: this seems like a bug to me, someone should report it. I think that adding color to grep is a common enough alias too... it's a one character fix to simply use `\grep` in the scrirpt. I added that to my `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make` and it was fixed. Can i split the bounty? Half should go to @etan-reisner and half to @ciprian-tomoiaga.

Comment: It is certainly a bug and should be reported. But color wasn't the problem (auto won't trigger there) the `-n` was.

Comment: @user1794469 Like I said in my comment on the post (I didn't realize someone else has posted the bounty) just accept and award this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look into `/etc/bash_completion`, `/etc/bash_completion.d` and/or `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`. You should find a file `make` which contains the script that will be called when press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Use the packaging system of your Linux distro to validate the file (or maybe revert to an older version).

Another cause of this could be something in the Makefile which throws the parser in the BASH completion script off the track.

Comment: there is no `make` file in the `/etc/bash_completion.d/` :(
In `/etc/bash_completion` no sign of `make` entry either ...

Comment: Then follow this advice: http://superuser.com/questions/142211/bash-completion-processing-gone-bad-how-to-debug

Comment: sorry to respawn this, but I still couldn't fix it. I lived with it for a few months, but now I'd really need it. Also, I don't think it's the Makefile, since it happens even with the most basic Makefile.
Also, can you see my edit, please? Thanks!

Comment: The `make` completion file is in folder `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to get any credits here, but the best solution is actually a bit hidden in the comments...
**Please vote [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932672/broken-tab-completion-on-make-under-linux?noredirect=1#comment50579741_31288089) up instead of my answer!**

easy steps to fix this:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make
```

find the line that has the grep instruction. It should look like this:

```
local reset=$( set +o | grep -F posix ); set +o posix # for <(...)
```

add a "**\**" before the "grep" instruction:

```
local reset=$( set +o | \grep -F posix ); set +o posix # for <(...)
```